# Docker mkdir C:: permission denied. / includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed

Tags: docker

when using this to run a Docker container:

```
docker run -d --name privacy-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=DockerPasswort! 
-e MYSQL_DATABASE=privacy-database -v C:/Users/Alexa/OneDrive/Backend-web-architecture/github-repos/data-privacy-api/db/db_records:/var/lib/mysql -v 
C:/Users/Alexa/OneDrive/Backend_web_architecture/github_repos/data-privacy-api/db/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d 
--network privacy-network -dit -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest 
--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

I get this error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: mkdir C:: permission denied. See
>   'docker run --help'.

When using this to run a Docker container:

```
docker run -d --name privacy-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=DockerPasswort! -e MYSQL_DATABASE=privacy-database -v db/db_records:/var/lib/mysql -v db/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d --network privacy-network -dit -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

I get this error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: create db/db_records:
>   "db/db_records" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, 
>       only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. 
>       If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
>       See 'docker run --help'.

How could I resolve one of the two problems?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check the Windows file permissions on the folder `C:/Users/Alexa/OneDrive/Backend-web-architecture/github-repos/data-privacy-api/db/db_records`

Comment: Forward-slashes in your Windows path?

Comment: @SiHa thank you this was a really good point! This worked! `docker run -d --name privacy-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=DockerPasswort! -e MYSQL_DATABASE=privacy-database -v db\db_records:/var/lib/mysql -v db\docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d --network privacy-network -dit -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password`